# Can't find file using Versions.GetVersions()

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to get the versions of a file in a SharePoint 2013 document library.

The library's URL is:

```
https://sps.abc.xyz.com/sites/map/DRC
```

I'm using the following class:

```
public class VersionFinder
{
    DRCCrawler.Versions.Versions versions = new DRCCrawler.Versions.Versions();

    public VersionFinder()
    {
        versions.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        versions.Url = "https://sps.abc.xyz.com/sites/map/DRC/_vti_bin/versions.asmx";    
    }

    public XmlNode GetVersions(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlNode ndDRCs = versions.GetVersions(filename);
            return ndDRCs;                
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error getting DRC.");       
        }
    }
}
```

I call `GetVersions()` as follows:

```
public void versionFinderTest()
{
    string filename = "https://sps.abc.xyz.com/sites/map/DRC/abcdefg.xlsm";
    VersionFinder vf = new VersionFinder();
    XmlNode node = vf.GetVersions(filename);
}
```

When I run this, the `versions.GetVersions()` web service call in `VersionFinder.GetVersions()` returns the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll

Additional information: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

But when I actually click on the `filename` URL from a hyperlink, the file successfully opens.  So is there a problem with the `filename` URL as it's used by Versions service?  Or maybe with how I initialized the Versions service?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but isn't the issue in how the `DRCCrawler.Versions.Versions.GetVersions` method is implemented? If so, please post that code, otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @DeanOC, that's a method in the Sharepoint Web Service (the web service provided by Microsoft).  Not sure how to view the implementation for that.